# YouTube Full-Screen video behind HTML content

Tags: html, css, video, youtube

I am embedding a YouTube video on http://demo.clc.agency/limbik/marcels/

If you click to play the video and select full-screen the navigation bar and 3 image blocks stay above the video. I'm not sure how I can display the video above all other content.

Another observation I made is that if the video was embedded on the second row, I do not get this problem.

I have tried setting the z-index but I cannot get the video to sit above the website content.

Comment: This problem appears only on Chrome. Firefox and IE works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `animate.css`. If you see in class `.animated` property `animation-fill-mode: both;`. This is the real problems with fullScreen in some browsers **[Read](https://github.com/matthieua/WOW/issues/115)** . This property is not required for simple fade in animation.

**[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323499/full-screen-video-issue-when-using-animate-css-in-chrome/32323618#32323618)**, He has mentioned it properly.

> This appears to be a Chrome bug. The problem is caused by the animation-fill-mode which is set to both. This keeps the animation active on the videos parent container, which seems to be messing with the full-screen video.

**Solution:**

You can override `animation-fill-mode`.

```
.wpb_start_animation.animated {
    animation-fill-mode: backwards;
}
```

or

```
.wpb_start_animation.animated {
   animation-fill-mode: none;
}
```